# Drag & Drop Shapes on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, canvas, shapes

I used `MouseDragElementBehavior` to let user drag & drop Shapes on a Canvas:

```
MouseDragElementBehavior dragBehavior = new MouseDragElementBehavior();
dragBehavior.Attach(myShape);
```

Now, I would like to know when myShape was moved and when myShape was dropped.
Could you please suggest a code that prints the mouse coordinates when myShape is moved, and prints "Dropped" when myShape is dropped ?
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MouseDragElementBehavior class has

- DragBegun
- DragFinished
- Dragging

events. I believe subscribing to those would do what you need